# form validation yml

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I would like to know if it is possible to define conditions in the validation.yml file...

```
vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Image:
  properties:
   color:
      - NotBlank: ~
   name:
      - NotBlank: ~
```

for example :
  field xxx is NotBlank if field yyyy = true

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Callback` validation:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Then, basically, you define the validation rules....